# Getting Started with AngularJs + Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am looking for good straight forward examples, tutorials, and books on AngularJs + Firebase that are **up-to-date** I have come across numerous tutorials on AngularJS + Firebase using simpleLogin.js which to my understanding is out-dated. I have read the [quickstart documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/quickstart.html) on firebase.com which provides examples on how to get started using firebase but not how to utilize firebase with angularjs. I am now go through [codecacademy's Firebase API course](https://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/firebase) but again it's not DI the api with angularjs it's showing standalone use.

It would be of great help if anyone can direct me to books on AngularJS + Firebase that are structured in the same way the authors of *A Smarter Way To Learning JavaScript* or *Learning Ruby The Hardway* have done.

Answer (score 3):

When I was starting to learn Angularfire, I found this tutorial to be incredibly useful: https://thinkster.io/angularfire-slack-tutorial. It shows you how to build a "slack clone" using angular and firebase, and I think it's still up-to-date. It was the best tutorial I found outside of what firebase has on their site.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good AngularJS/Firebase examples on https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/.

I'm actually the author of the first example, "Wait and Eat". The app is open source, so you can learn a lot by just poking around in the code, and if you have any questions, you can ask me (my contact info is in the [README](https://github.com/gordonmzhu/angular-course-demo-app-v2)).

I keep it up-to-date and it also follows best practices from the Angular Style Guide from John Papa.

If you want more guidance, I also have a [video course](https://watchandcode.com/courses/angular-course) where you build the app step-by-step as [22Ryann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3620044/22ryann) mentioned.